# IntelliJ Vim plugin doesn't support capture groups?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, regex-group

I'm beginning to use IntelliJ with the vim plugin, and found that commands as simple as

```
/case (.*)
```

fail to return any results.  Of course, that's not a very useful command.  I'd like to reverse the order of all of the elements of my table by executing

```
:'<,'>s/case (\w*): return (\w*);/case \2: return \1;/
```

but that also failed to match anything.  I tried a few different search regexes and all of them worked as long as there were no capture groups.

Does IntelliJ Vim support capture groups like these?  Are there special characters I need to escape to get it to work?  I know the builtin search and replace gui lets you do logic with backreferences, but I'd like to do my work right from the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This wouldn't even work in Vim to begin with.

`(\w*)` is not a capture group; it will match a *literal* opening parenthesis, followed by any number of any keyword character, followed by a *literal* closing parenthesis.

`\(\w*\)` is an actual capture group… which will work both in Vim *and* in IdeaVim.

Comment: bruh. why is `*` a metacharacter while `(` and `)` are not.

Comment: @AlexMandelias, because the history of regular expressions is messy and confusing and what constitutes a metacharacter or not is highly context-dependent.